# How do you make custom legends in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to get a legend in ggplot2 that will display the label and color of my data with this code:

```
valueVector <- vector()
breakVector <- vector()
foo <- as.data.frame(Seatbelts)
p <- ggplot(foo, aes(x=drivers, y=DriversKilled))  
p <- p + geom_line(aes(y = front, colour = "front"), size = .5)
valueVector <- c(valueVector,"red")
breakVector <- c(breakVector,"front") 
p <- p + geom_line(aes(y = rear, colour = "rear"), size = .5)
valueVector <- c(valueVector,"blue")
breakVector <- c(breakVector,"rear")
p <- p + geom_line(aes(y = kms/100, colour = "kms"), size = .5)
valueVector <- c(valueVector,"green")
breakVector <- c(breakVector,"kms")  
p <- p + geom_line(aes(y = VanKilled, colour = "VanKilled"), size = .5)
valueVector <- c(valueVector,"black")
breakVector <- c(breakVector,"VanKilled")
p <- p + scale_colour_manual("", values = valueVector, breaks = breakVector)
```

At this point, valueVector = c("red", "blue", "green", "black"),

breakVector =  c("front", "rear", "kms", "VanKilled"),

and p creates a graph where front = red, rear = green, kms = blue, and VanKilled  = black.

As you can see the order of the values has been shuffled, and subsequently the colors aren't what I tried to set them as. I can't find any rhyme or reason to this, it seems to be different every time I make a new graph. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going the wrong way about this. ggplot2 uses a framework to create graphics, which takes some familiarity. You should read some introductory material. Here's the basic idea for your example,

```
d <- data.frame(Seatbelts)
d$kms <- d$kms/100

require(reshape2) # to transform the data into long format
m <- melt(d, meas = c("front", "rear", "kms", "VanKilled"))

# now we map the variables to aesthetic parameters
ggplot(m, aes(drivers, value, colour=variable)) +
  geom_line()
```

Comment: That's fair but I still don't understand why the parameters in my question's code aren't applied in order. I'll try to restructure my code to work with melt() but if you have any insight on why R behaved like that it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have little insight into what happens when you use a string inside `aes()`; it's not really meant to be used that way so strange things can happen...

Comment: Alright, thanks. I had been doing it that way based on a previous stack overflow answer and it might have been a rather hacked together fix.